# How make multicolumns pipes filter?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular2-services

I have such a paipe and it will work only for the column: name a for the author no longer.

```
export class FilterBook2 implements PipeTransform {
```

`transform(items: Book[], filter: Book): any {
    if (!items || !filter) {
        return items;
    }

    // filter items array, items which match and return true will be kept, false will be filtered out

    return items.filter((item) => item.Nazwa.indexOf(filter.Nazwa) || item.Autor.indexOf(filter.Autor)  !== -1)

}`

}

Input date:

filterargs = { Nazwa: "", Autor: "" }

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to filter books by multiple arguments. You can pass multiple values to the pipe transform function like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of books | filterBook2 : firstArg : secondArg">
    ...
</div>
```

and in the pipe class

```
export class FilterBook2 implements PipeTransform {
   transform(items: Book[], firstArg: Book, secondArg: any): any {
       // your logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in passing paramars. I think so. The problem seems to be in the line: return items.filter((item) => item.Nazwa.indexOf(filter.Nazwa) || item.Autor.indexOf(filter.Autor)  !== -1)